# AnyLogic one output port to multiple input ports

Tags: queue, anylogic

I have a WITNESS model that I am trying to convert into AnyLogic one. The WITNESS model has a buffer (queue) with capacity 10 that gets its entities pulled to two different conveyors. I wanna do the same thing in AnyLogic, what I tried to do was as simple as that:

[image: AnyLogic Queue to multiple conveyors]

But when modeling that way I get an error:

[image: AnyLogic error]

I am using the Free Personal Learning Edition of AnyLogic 7, I learned that this operation is supported by the enterprise library at least for version 6 (see https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=/com.xj.anylogic.help/html/_Enterprise/Ports.html), but is there a way to do it using the free licence?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to put a "Select Output" object after the queue. In there, you specify the condition of where each entity should go. If it depends on the downstream object's state, you need to specify that in Java code.

In your screen, you have conveyors downstream. They have build-in functions that check if there is enough space yet to take an object yet (check the help on conveyors, I think it is something like nadrzLCZ.hasCapacity() or similar.

Also read up on push and pull protocols and how to set up your required setup. Sounds like you want the conveyors to pull, right?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I was afraid that would be the answer, since I'm trying to use AnyLogic for teaching porpuses I did not want to abuse the use of java code. A important note is that I could not find such ".hasCapacity()" method or anything similar for the AnyLogic Conveyor, instead I had to use variables to manually keep track of it.

Comment: there is a "canEnter()" method that might help. It checks if another entity can enter by now or not.